# Private keys cannot be verified in recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, signature-error

I am trying to sign zip packages before flashing them in recovery. By using the test keys by Google, the zip can be verified and flashed successfully. However, when I try to sign using my private keys, the signing process is OK but the verification always fails.

**First method:**
Using keytool and jarsigner

Generating private keys:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore test.keystore alias zippack -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 1000
```

Signing:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore test.keystore test.zip zippack
```

Result:

```
E: signature verification failed
```

**Second method (a):** 
Using OpenSSL and SignApk.jar

Generating private keys:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out request.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 9999 -in request.pem -signkey key.pem -out certificate.pem
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -outform DER -in key.pem -inform PEM -out key.pk8 -nocrypt
```

Signing:

```
java -jar -w signapk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8 test.zip test-signed.zip
```

Result:

```
E: failed to verify whole file signature
I: verify_file returned 1
E: signature verification failed
```

**Second method (b):**
OpenSSL and SignApk.jar (changes in commands)

Generating private keys:

```
Same as above
```

Signing:

```
java -jar signapk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8 test.zip test-signed.zip
```

Result:

```
E: signature verification failed
```

That's about what I did. The methods above works for APKs, but not for zips. Anyone can help on this? Thanks in advanced.

P.S. I managed to get a look at the source code for recovery, and found that my errors are generated by this part of the code: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_bootable_recovery/blob/jellybean/verifier.c Maybe it might help answering.

Comment: This looks like a programming question, and should be on StackOverflow.com instead.

Comment: I don't think so because this is not programming, it is something related to the internals of Android OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code comments:

```
// ... Verify it matches one of the given public
// keys.
```

You can't just use any old signature, that would defeat the purpose.  APKs, on the other hand, are intended to be created and distributed by anyone and the signature is ostensibly to *verify* the source rather than *limit* the source.